# Iterative Combobox cannot add "AND" Operator in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

```
<lightning-button label="Edit" onclick={handleEdit}></lightning-button>   
<template for:each={productAccess} for:item="item" for:index="indexVar">
                                <tr key={item.productId} class="slds-hint-parent">
                                
                                         <td class="slds-size_1-of-5">
                                        <div>
                                            {item.Name}
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    <td class="slds-size_1-of-5">
                                        <div>
                                            {item.Price}
                                        </div>
                                    </td>

                                      <td class="slds-size_2-of-5">
                                    <div>
                                        
                                         <lightning-combobox
                                            name={item}
                                            id={item.productId}
                                            **disabled={item.check && disableFlag}**
                                            value={item.status}
                                            placeholder="Select Status"
                                            options={options}
                                            onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox> 
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                   
                                </tr>
                            </template>
```

js

```
 handleEdit(event)
 {
     
     this.disableFlag = false;
 }
```

When user click on edit button i'm making disableFlag = false and i need to check item.check as well into show or not how do i acheive this ?

Answer (score 1):

We can't put a logical expression in LWC markup. However, you can achieve it with js. You can add an additional property to the array being iterated.

```
<template for:each={products} for:item="product" for:index="index">
    <lightning-combobox key={product.Name} access-key={product.Id} label={product.disabled} options={options}
        disabled={product.disabled} onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>



handleChange(event){
    const { accessKey } = event.currentTarget;
    this.products = this.products.map(product => product.Id === accessKey ? ({ ...product, disabled: true && !false }) : product);
  }
```

You can put condition the way you want. `...product, disabled: product.check && this.disableFlag`

[Here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/kJRKguCAKGqCAS0NPz82/src/app.html) is a playground example you can refer.

Comment: how do i make it disabled condition based on both product disabled and button onclick ?

Comment: ! thanks .. Great idea